# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'users') | interaction.client.api.users | Discord.js V14

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This Error:
[image: Console Error]

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'users')
    at Object.execute (D:\Mortal\Belgeler\Kod Denemeleri\Discord Botu\Via\v4 (v14)\commands\Kullanıcı\profil.js:34:55)
    at module.exports (D:\Mortal\Belgeler\Kod Denemeleri\Discord Botu\Via\v4 (v14)\events\interactionCreate.js:28:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

---

And this my code:
[image: Error]

```js
const APIFetch = await interaction.client.api.users(user ? user.id : interaction.user.id).get()
```

I could not find the solution to the problem on the internet because it is a new version. I researched for about 2 hours; At first, I looked at the sites and then looked at what data I could pull through interaction or the client. We can't pull API data. That's why we get the error "users" can't be read. At least that's it, as I understand it... How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use interaction.client.users directly:

```js
const data = await interaction.client.users.fetch(user ? user.id : interaction.user.id);
```